# IE z-index relative/absolute bug in list

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following navigation where .topNav has position:relative and subnav has position:absolute. I cant get the sublist to appear over the main list due to z-index problems. This seems to be a known problem.

```
<ul>
<li class="topNav">About Us
<ul class="subNav"><li> Subsection A</li><li>Subsection B</li></ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Does anyone know of a workaround?

---

UPDATE http://brh.numbera.com/experiments/ie7_tests/zindex.html shows exacly the problem I have. My original posting was in the context of a list but I have reduced the problem to the fact that z-index dosn't seem to work when have an element with position:absolute inside a parent element with position:relative

---

Comment: What do the styles look like or are they literally just setting position?

Comment: ive stripped out everything from the styles apart from the positioning as I've proved to myself that this is where the problem lies

Comment: Could you explain a bit more fully what effect you're trying to achieve please. By over do you mean above or overlaid on top of?

Comment: If you've got the CSS code, or if it's uploaded somewhere that we could see it, we might be able to help. As it is, we don't know what you're doing to that markup so it could be absolutely anything...

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue, but depending on what you are trying to do.. the effect is different across all browsers, what is your intention and are the elements always displayed?

Comment: http://brh.numbera.com/experiments/ie7_tests/zindex.html shows exacly the problem I have. My original posting was in the context of a list but I have reduced the problem to the fact that z-index dosn't seem to work when have an element with position:absolute inside a parent element with position:relative

Comment: AJM, actually, the problem appears when you have two sibling elements, both with position:relative and same value for z-index. Also, the first element contains a child element with position:absolute;

If you could post more code I could try to fix it, unless there's the above situation.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a very good article that explains the stacking issues that machineghost mentions.

http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

What you might want to consider (depending on why you're wanting the positioning on multiple elements) is adding a hover selector to .base (use JavaScript for IE6) that adds the class to give it relativity.

```
.base:hover{position:relative;}
```

This then means that the second .base doesn't have position: relative.

Comment: great article, i thought I understood z-index etc but I actually do now and I've solved the problem.

Comment: I know this is an Old post - but AJM would you mind sharing your solution, as I can't seem to find the proper fix for the above .base css test on Ben's website, while keeping both .base div as position:relative.

Comment: Nice trick applying the relative positioning on :hover, solved my IE7 problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think your problem probably stems from a lack of understanding about how z-index works.  The z-index property is only relevant for elements **at the same level in the DOM hierarchy**.  In other words, if you have:

```
<ul id="a">
  <li id="b">b</li>
  <li id="c">c</li>
</ul>
<div id="d"></div>
```

and "b" and "c" are styled such that they overlap, z-index will determine which one ends up on top.  However, if "c" and "d" overlap, "d" will always be on top, no matter what c's z-index is, because elements that are closer to the root DOM node will always appear above elements that are nested deeper in.

So, as long as "subnNav" is a child of "topNav," I don't think there is any way to make it cover it's parent's content.  In other words, as far as I know there is no workaround for this issue, except to make "subNav" not be a child of "topNav".

(NOTE: All that being said, CSS is not simple, so there may still be some way to get the effect you want that I'm not aware of.  All I can say is that, based on my understanding of z-index and my pretty good general CSS knowledge, there's no way that I know of.)

Comment: I've been doing web development for 15 years and I've never heard that z-index only applies to elements at the same level in the DOM Hierarchy. Can you quote a source or spec that states this? I'm very curious.

Comment: I can't ... or to be more accurate, I spent a minute on Google, got lazy, and gave up :-)  However, I can make an example that "proves" this.  In the following code, if you remove the z-index properties, you'll see a green box in the upper-left corner, because a/b/c all have the same z-index (and c, which is green, comes last).  However, with the z-indexs in, you'll see ... a green box ... even though b (yellow) has a higher z-index than c; c still "trumps" b because it is higher in the DOM tree.

Comment: <style>
#a, #b, #c {position:absolute; left:0;top:0; width:100px; height:100px;}
#a {background-color: red; z-index:1}
#b {background-color: yellow; z-index:3}
#c {background-color: green; z-index:2}
</style>
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
<div id="c"></div>

Answer (score 1):

adding

```
background: url(blank.gif);
```

for absolutely positioned elemnts solves the problem for me. Mybe it can helps u 2 :)

regards

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was able to fix it In IE6 and 7. Combining http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ with the following CSS the issue went away. With my issue I had some items inside a list floated left and had a tooltip that popped up whenever the user hovered over the li. To fix it, I adde this:

`.ul li:hover {position:relative;z-index:4;}
.ul li:hover + li {position:relative;z-index:3;}`

The way it works is whenever the user hovers over the first LI for example, it sets the second LI floated next to it to a lower z-index value. You can of course change the z-index values to fit your own needs.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me. ;)

http://ltslashgt.com/2007/05/16/relative-zindex-and-ie/

Answer (score 0):

Stu Nicholls at CSSplay has a get [CSS Based nav w/ 6 level drop down](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/simple_vertical.html) (Can be expanded to more if needed). This works in Internet Explorer IE5.5, IE6, IE7, Firefox, Opera and now Safari, Netscape 8 and Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: assign z-index in decreasing order

```
<div class="base" style="z-index:2">
<div class="inside">
    This has some more text in it. This also has a background. This should obscure the second block of text since it has a higher z-index.
</div>
This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it.
</div>

<div class="base" style="z-index:1">
This is the second div. You should not be seeing this in front of the grey box. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This has some text in it. This second box should be obscured by the grey box.
</div>
```

Comment: This works for divs, but the op is asking about styling a list. I'm running into the same problem currently.

Comment: the solution above doesn't work in IE7 using the same css stylesheet as found on http://brh.numbera.com/experiments/ie7_tests/zindex.html

Answer (score 0):

Similar to answer by @Orhaan, setting a background property to the absolute element is the only solution that worked for me...

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

[Thanks Alex Leonoard](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/01/27/ie-bug-text-ignores-z-index-of-higher-elements/)