# position: relative appearing over position:absolute

Tags: css

Having a strange issue in IE7. In a number of spots, I have a DIV which has position: absolute on it (faux dropdown) whenever there is something behind it which has position: relative the relative positioned item will show through the other div.

Relativly positioned item does not have any z-index set, while the absolutely positioned item (the one I want on top) has a z-index of 1000.

http://skitch.com/louiswalch/dub5h/microsoft-windows-vista

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE z-index relative/absolute bug in list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798482/ie-z-index-relative-absolute-bug-in-list)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I suspect you've already tried it, but set a `z-index` on your relatively positioned element that's lower than your absolutely positioned element's `z-index` as the first test.

If that doesn't work, you need to make sure both elements are in the same [stacking context](http://therealcrisp.xs4all.nl/meuk/IE-zindexbug.html).  In IE, whenever you apply the `position` CSS rule to an element, it generates a new stacking context within that element.  That means that z-index will only be properly respected within that element's children and children in other stacking contexts *with* lower z-indexes may still stack above.

In your case, you either need to put the dropdown and button in the same stacking context **or** apply z-index to the 2 elements that are generating their separate stacking contexts.

Comment: Ahh spot on, that's the problem. Problem is I'm not sure I can put them in the same stacking index. It's happening on another place on the site which has a more complex layout and the element with relative positioning is in a total different level of the DOM. I tried giving the item which is popping through a z-index lower then the item above it and it still shows though. what does "or apply z-index to the 2 elements that are generating their separate stacking contexts. " mean?

Comment: What I mean is that you have to find the 2 parent elements with a `position` set (these are creating the 2 separate stacking contexts) and set `z-index` on them.  For example if your button is nested in a container called `#content` and your dropdown is in `#header`, you could set `#content { z-index: 1 } and `#header { z-index: 2 }`.  Provided `#header` and `#content` are in the same stacking context, this will fix your problem.