# How to show hidden div on top of other divs positioned absolute?

Tags: html, css

I'm working with MVC3 to create a simple website. But the thing is with CSS. I have created a header page, and added my menu to it (I want the menu to be displayed on all pages). For submenus, I have created hidden divs for each menu item, which are displayed when menu-items are hovered over and disappears when hovered out.  Everything is fine for other pages but on one of the pages, I was creating slide effect using fadeIn() fadeOut() of 3 images contained in a single div, positioned absolute(so that they lie over each other). But now the hidden divs don't come above(z-index towards user) but comes below the images and thus cannot be seen completely. I have tried altering z-indexes of hidden divs and images but that didn't help. How to bring the hidden divs on top??

Comment: Z-Index is the key, so try again. http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index

Comment: I think I found the problem. It maybe same as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538583/position-relative-appearing-over-positionabsolute

Comment: Thnx. The problem was really z-index related, but I didn't knew separate stacking contexts were generated and z-indexes were relative. I set the z-index of whole menu(whose position was set relative,creating different stacking context) to 1000 and z-index of div(position set to absolute) to 100.

Comment: can you provide us a jsFiddle please ?

Comment: Did you try setting display:inline-block;?