# Ie 7-9 not displaying position:absolute correctly

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, z-index, absolute

I have a div with z-index:1-100(changes with javascript) and position:absolute. inside that i have an a href with z-index:101 and position:absolute.

All webbbrowsers renders this as the one with 101 is displayed on top (correctly)
but in ie 7-8-9 it doesnt... why is that?
Could really use some help here!!

CODE:

```
     <div id="bannerad">
     <a target="_blank" style="position:absolute;z-index:101;width:680px;height:120px;" class="mcdFade" href="http://www.mcdonalds.se"></a>
     <div id="fadea" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/1.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>
     <div id="fadeb" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/2.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>
     <div id="fadec" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/3.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>   
     </div>
```

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

generated by visual studio

**EDIT 2**
Added jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pesmd/18/ but cant get it to work, you only see the image slightly, it works in my browser though

**Edit 3**
This seems to be a major problem in IE, i have tried the solutions i found without result. Is there no1 here that can help me with this problem?

What i know, the z-index property resets when you have a parent with a position other then default set to them, but i still cant get it to work.

Comment: Have you declared a doc type in IE?

Comment: Cant seem to get it to work in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Pesmd/18/

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's too convoluted for me to want to spend any time trying to fix it. I've removed my answer.

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/798482/144496

Comment: Checked it, and i cant see the similarities of the questions. The problem they were was with the position:relative; inside a position absolute, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

set anchor to display:block see if that works. Then add a big 3px green border on the element when your testing so you can see it better.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just wrap your link around the divs?

```
<div id="bannerad"> 
    <a target="_blank" style="position:absolute;z-index:101;width:680px;height:120px;" class="mcdFade" href="http://www.mcdonalds.se">
        <div id="fadea" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/1.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>
        <div id="fadeb" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/2.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>
        <div id="fadec" style="position:absolute;visibility:hidden;"><img src="Images/Ads/McDHstad/3.jpg" width="800" height="120" alt="Fade"/></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**Edit:** I looked at your fiddle and made it work.  It's a different design than you were going for, but it's simple and gets the job done without having to worry about z-index:  http://jsfiddle.net/kCsvG/3/